# event entities in telethon

Tags: python, entities, telethon

i have a problem with entites when emoji is in text.

it is my text :

```
❓️❓
abcdefghijklmnop
@aaabbbbbcccc
```

and it is my entities event:

`entities=[ MessageEntityMention( length=13, offset=49 ), ]`

and my code :

```
txt = event.raw_text
print(event.message.message)
if event.message.entities != None:
   i=0
   c = len(event.message.entities)
   while i<c:
       a = event.message.entities[i]
       if (type(a) is MessageEntityMention) == True:
          print(a)
          o = a.offset
          l = a.length
          eo = o + l
          txt = txt.replace(event.raw_text[o:eo],"@example")
       i=i+1
   print(txt)
```

This should change the ID(@aaabbbbbcccc) to @example, but it does not, and return:

```
❓️❓
abcdefghijklmnop
@aaabbbbb@example
```

The problem is due to the emojis. It works fine when I delete the emojis.

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
async def handler(event): 
    content = event.raw_text
    for ent, txt in event.get_entities_text():
        # ent : shows you the MessageEntity constructor
        # txt : shows you the text interested
        if isinstance(ent, types.MessageEntityMention): # check if it's a mention
            content = content.replace(txt, '@example')
```

Check out the [telethon docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.message.Message.get_entities_text) for more informations about `get_entities_text`.

Answer (score 0):

The offsets are calculated in text with surrogates, so you need to add them before doing operations with [`helpers.add_surrogate`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/helpers.html#telethon.helpers.add_surrogate):

```py
from telethon import helpers

text = helpers.add_surrogate(message.raw_text)

... # work with `text` and `message.entities` (offsets will be OK now)

text = helpers.del_surrogate(text)  # remove the surrogate pairs when done
```

The method showcased by TheKill in their answer is a better fit depending on your situation, but this is how that works underneath in case you need it.